# Woocommerce: Add column to ORDERS admin page with items purchased

Tags: wp-admin, woocommerce-offtopic, order

After updating to Woocommerce 3.0, in the Woocommerce ORDER page (where you can check all the orders made by customers, with order status, billing address, shipping address, total, etc.) is missing the column with the items purchased by the customer.
Before WC update, that column was there. Now it is gone.

Could anyone help me to add again this column?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is a free plugin that restores it to just like it was before: https://wordpress.org/plugins/restore-purchased-items-column/

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/336355/174108
how can add a category or tag or products thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have already manage to create a column thanks to this:

```
    // ADDING COLUMN TITLES
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column',11);
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
   //add columns
    $columns['my-column1'] = __( 'Column Title','theme_slug');
   return $columns;
}

// adding the data for each orders by column (example)
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column )
{
    global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;
    $order_id = $the_order->id;

    switch ( $column )
    {
        case 'my-column1' :
            $myVarOne = wc_get_order_item_meta( $order_id, '_the_meta_key1', true );
            echo $myVarOne;
            break;
    }
```

But I don't know how to add the data to this columns. I need to add the items purchased by the customers. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this to add an `Ordered Products` column right after the `Date` column (fits nicely there). Each product is also linked to it's proper edit page.

```
// ----- add column to orders that shows which products were ordered -----
function ec_order_items_column($columns) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach($columns as $key=>$column){
        $new_columns[$key] = $columns[$key];
        if($key === 'order_date') {
            $new_columns['ordered_products'] = __('Ordered Products','woo-custom-ec');
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;

    //$columns['order_products'] = "Purchased Items";
    //return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'ec_order_items_column', 99 );

// ----- add data to new column that shows which products were ordered -----
function ec_order_items_column_cnt($column) {
    global $the_order; // the global order object
    if($column == 'ordered_products') {
        // get items from the order global object
        $order_items = $the_order->get_items();
        if (!is_wp_error($order_items)) {
            foreach($order_items as $order_item) {
                echo $order_item['quantity'].'&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;<a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post='.$order_item['product_id'].'&action=edit' ).'">'.$order_item['name'].'</a><br />';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'ec_order_items_column_cnt', 99);
```

[image]

Comment: At woocommerce 7.7 this not working when enable feature `High-Performance order storage (COT)`. Have any update for this code?

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: My code above is a hook for `wp_posts` admin tables ... Enabling (HPOS) moves the orders out of `wp_posts` and into their own custom database tables ... I do not have any experience with (HPOS) yet so I do not have any modified code to mange (HPOS) order tables ... maybe some day, but not today.

Comment: Many thanks. Hope you help. Your code very short but it very helpful. I can see the name of product and quality order.

Comment: hi @Scotty G, do you have time to research that code?

Comment: hi @Scooty G. Are you have free time. Can you help me custom this code for HPOS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the purchased products in a column, you can use this code:

```
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column )
{
    global $the_order;
    $order_id = $the_order->id;

    switch ( $column )
    {
        case 'my-column1' :
            $order_items = $the_order->get_items();
            foreach( $order_items as $myVarOne ) {
                echo $myVarOne['quantity'] .'&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;'. $myVarOne['name'] .'<br />';
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

You can also view the complete code with screenshots in [this tutorial](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/columns.html#purchased_products_column).